# Giving users the allusion of a free trial

Tags: swift, xcode, in-app-subscription

I am offering a subscription to users right when they sign up to my iOS app. If the user does not purchase the subscription offer at sign up, I want to give them the premium version of the app for 7 days. Once the 7 days past I want the user to have to purchase a subscription to continue to use the app.

I do not want to do just a basic counter/timer in the app because users' can just delete and reinstall the app to get full access once their time is up.

What is a possible way of accomplishing this?

Comment: save their phone UUID in backend

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for business modelling and not programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple provides a way to do that. but it supports iOS **11.0+** It's called [DeviceCheck](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck)

From the docs:

> Access per-device, per-developer data that your associated server can
>   use in its business logic.

You can set two bits data per device and keep in mind that it is dev's responsibility for keeping track of whether a user is entitled to redeem any offer that you provide.

A good way to [start](https://medium.com/the-traveled-ios-developers-guide/devicecheck-6f3eafac60e5)